# How to open dialog in onHandleIntent() method of an IntentService class

Tags: android

I want to open a custom dialog in  `onHandleIntent()` method of an `IntentService` class, but when I write code for showing Dialog in this method it shows error

`The method findViewById(int) is undefined for the type MyAlarmService`

Can anyone suggest me how to solve this issue?

Code I have used:

```
public class MyAlarmService extends IntentService { 
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
}

public MyAlarmService() {
    super("MyAlarmService");
}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    super.onStartCommand(intent, startId, startId);
    Toast.makeText(this, "MyAlarmService.onStart()", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    return START_STICKY;
}
            
@SuppressWarnings("static-access")
@Override
protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
    final Dialog alarmDialog = new Dialog(MyAlarmService.this);
    alarmDialog .requestWindowFeature(alarmDialog.getWindow().FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    alarmDialog .getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(0));

    Context mContext = getApplicationContext();
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.clear_all_warning_dialog, (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.layout_warning_dialog));
    
    TextView dialogTitile = (TextView) layout.findViewById(R.id.dialog_title_text);
    
    TextView dialogDesc = (TextView) layout.findViewById(R.id.dialog_desc_text);
    
    Button buttonYes = (Button) layout.findViewById(R.id.button_yes);               
    
    Button buttonNo = (Button) layout.findViewById(R.id.button_no);             

    alarmDialog.setContentView(layout);
    alarmDialog.show();
    
    buttonYes.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {                    
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            alarmDialog.dismiss();
        }
    }); 
    buttonNo.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {                 
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            alarmDialog.dismiss();
        }
    }); 
}
}
```

Comment: it's possible to show Dialog from service????

Comment: But in my case i have to used IntentService class, So do u know how to show dialog inside IntentService class. secondly if i use service class my app is always shown in running process instead of cache process

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It can be done just start an **activity** instead of thinking of inflating dialogs:

```
@Override
protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
    synchronized (this) 
  {
    startActivity(new Intent(this,ActivityXYZ.class).setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK));
  }
}
```

Make the **Dialog Layout**(Which is an ActivityXYZ's layout, that you started above) like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="#000"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/TextView01"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:text="Alert Dialog Message"
    android:textColor="#fff"
    android:textSize="16dp" >
</TextView>
<LinearLayout  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp">

<Button
    android:id="@+id/ButtonOk"
    android:layout_width="150dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:text="Ok"
    android:textColor="#000"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    android:textStyle="bold" >
</Button>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/ButtonCancel"
    android:layout_width="150dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:text="Cancel"
    android:textColor="#000"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
   >
</Button>
</LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

and in Manifest file include this in that **activity's configuration**:

```
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog"
```

While making your layout for that activity just add text view and two buttons as done in Dialogs and it will give an effect of Dialog inflated from Service.

For any clarifications let me know. :))))

Comment: You mean to say, i can start a new activity and in that activity i should open a dialog. But is that activity open as an dilaog..can u explain me with an example

Comment: No, it will pop-up as a dialog. Just make an activity and in its layout put two buttons and a textview. Add the <android:theme>(as mentioned above) code in manifest under the activity name where you have defined it, and it will surely work. For the 2 buttons you can put onClickListeners like in my case I used to start a HomeScreen which used to give a feel like I started an application from Dialog Box. If you still need help or clarification let me know, I'll try to explain with code.

Comment: Be sure you add it in the same project where your service is running. Hope it helps.

Comment: ok great I have modified my post and included codes in case you require.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can inflate views in a service, since IntentService doesn't run on the UI thread, another solution would be to bind your service to your activity and write a listener which will show the dialog and register it to your service in the onBind() method.

You can extend your service the following way:

```
public class MyAlarmService extends IntentService {

    private MyListener mListener;

    // Your implementation here

    public void registerListener(MyListener listener){
        mListener = listener;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
                listener.postToUIThread();

        // Other things you might want to do
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return new MyAlarmBinder(this);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onUnbind(Intent intent) {
        return super.onUnbind(intent);
    }
}
```

Then write the binder and listener as follows:

```
public class MyListener {

    private Handler mHandler;
    private Runnable mRunnable;

    public MyListener(Handler handler, Runnable runnable){
        this.mHandler = handler;
        this.mRunnable = runnable;
    }

    public void postToUIThread(){
        mHandler.post(mRunnable);
    }
}

public class MyAlarmBinder extends Binder {
    private WeakReference<MyAlarmService> mService;

    public MyAlarmBinder(MyAlarmService service){
        mService = new WeakReference<MyAlarmService>(service);
    }

    public MyAlarmService getService(){
        return mService.get();
    }
}
```

Notice, that in the listener I use a Handler created on the UI thread to post the dialog creation code to the UI thread.

And in your main activity you can put it together:

```
private MyAlarmService mService;

private Handler mHandler = new Handler;
private Runnable mRunnable = new Runnable(){

    @Override
    public void run(){
        // Show dialog here
    }
}

private ServiceConnection mConnection = new ServiceConnection() {

    public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName name, IBinder service) {
        mService = ((MyAlarmBinder)service).getService();
        mService.registerListener(new MyListener(mHandler, mRunnable));
    }

    public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName name) {
        mService = null;
    }
};

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    bindService(new Intent(this, MyAlarmService.class), mConnection,
        Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    if(mConnection != null){
        unbindService(mConnection);
    }
}
```

I didn't try this, but with slight modifications this should solve your problems. If you have any other questions please don't hesitate to ask.